# Los mensajes por Websocekets tienen un retraso de más de 5 minutos en angular

Tags: angular, websocket, angular9

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en angular 9, donde un servidor manda información cada 5 milisegundos, aproximadamente 27.000 mensajes y el último mensaje es recibido hasta 10 minutos después del envio.

```
onMessageListener() {
this.ws.onmessage = (event) => {
  const time = new Date();
  console.log(
    `recived at: ${time.getHours()}:${time.getMinutes()}:${time.getSeconds()}.${time.getMilliseconds()}`
  );
  console.log('from service: ', event?.data);
};
  }

connect(wsUrl: string) {
    if (!this.ws || this.ws.readyState === this.ws.CLOSED) {
      this.ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl);
    }

    this.onOpenListener();
    this.onMessageListener();
    this.onCloseListener(wsUrl);
    this.onErrorListener(wsUrl);
  }
```

Por otra parte encontré este simple ejemplo en un tag de script dentro de un HTML, lo probé y la diferencia con la misma cantidad de datos es de aproximadamente 10 segundos, escribiendo los mensajes en el html y no en consola. A que se debe esta gran diferencia?

Intenté también crear un Js con las funciones en el ejemplo encontrado e importarlo al proyecto de angular, lo puedo utilizar en el componente pero no el tiempo no mejora, por lo tanto encuentro que el inconveniente se presenta del lado de Angular

> https://www.websocket.org/echo.html

```
function testWebSocket()
  {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
  }

function onMessage(evt)
  {
    let time = new Date();
    let dateRecived = time.getHours()+":"+time.getMinutes()+":"+time.getSeconds()+"."+time.getMilliseconds() +'::>>';
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + dateRecived + evt.data+'</span>');
  }
```

Comment: depende del tamaño de los mensajes... es una burrada

Comment: te dejo el link de unas pruebas y sus resultados https://habr.com/en/post/460847/

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo @Srsole, por fa mira mi ultima respuesta que hace parte de la misma pregunta, donde sin utilizar Angular, la diferencia solo es de 10 segundos

Comment: angular no deja de ser un framework, y JS puro le da mil vueltas, no lo dudes

Comment: ademas ten en cuenta la latencia entre maquinas y server, yo subiria el tiempo, minimo a 1 segundo.

Comment: ¿Algo que pueda hacer para mejorar estos tiempos?

Comment: depende, que pretendes hacer con el socket?

Comment: Se trata de unas graficas en tiempo real, la información se genera y se envía por el Websocket cada 5 milisegundos @Srsole

Comment: Yo el problema que veo es que parece claro que el cuello de botella está en Angular... pero no sabemos qué estás haciendo con Angular mientras se procesan los mensajes. ¿Intentas visualizarlos?

Comment: Esa es la idea procesar esa información para alimentar tres gráficas, pero al ver el retraso, lo que hice fue comentar todo tipo de procesamiento y únicamente escribir en consola la hora exacta en la que recibo cada mensaje, para medir el tiempo, y aún así con solo escribir en consola, el retraso es muy alto @PabloLozano

Comment: ¿Y si no escribes en consola? Has probado a esperar a tener todo para mostrar algo?

Comment: La verdad no puedo esperar a tener todo, porque es información que se debe mostrar en "tiempo real", lo más pronto posible a su generación @PabloLozano

Comment: Puedes llegar a un compromiso: nadie puede leer en 5 milisegundos, así que podrías acumular 40 mensajes (200 milisegundos) y entonces actualizar

Answer (score 0):

Creo que a tu navegador no le da tiempo a procesar los mensajes: Sólo escribir en consola mensajes, cada 5 milisegundos ya acumula retraso. He puesto un ejemplo con 200 llamadas a `console.log`, cada una a los 5ms y ya necesita más de 11 segundos (un segundo sobre lo esperado). Ahora imagina además procesar un mensaje recibido desde un servidor.

```js
let count = 0;
const start = performance.now();
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  const time = new Date();
  console.log(`Time: ${time.getHours()}:${time.getMinutes()}:${time.getSeconds()}.${time.getMilliseconds()}`);
  if (count++ > 2000) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    timed();
  }
}, 5);

function timed () {
  console.log((performance.now()-start)/1000);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo, porfa revisa mi ultimo comentario, donde explico otro ejemplo que utilicé pero sin angular, y el tiempo de diferencia se reduce a solo 10segundos

Comment: for(var a = 0;a <200;a++){console.log("mensaje");}  tiempo tomado: 3.139 milis

Comment: claro, pero ahí no estás procesando un string template, ni creando un objeto Date y luego parseándolo... ni explicas qué haces realmente con los resultados en Angular. Si por cada mensaje que recibes muestras algo en un componente de Angular, estás añadiendo una sobrecarga enorme: ejecución de los métodos ngOnChanges para cada componente visible, renderizado del template.... etc

Comment: js puro, nada de frame